# Search Column name in Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to find particular column in Linked Server's database within all tables.

I guess solution lies in

```
EXEC sp_columns_ex
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name as TableName, c.name as ColumnName
FROM servernamehere.databasenamehere.sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN servernamehere.databasenamehere.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name like '%yoursearchhere%'
```

Comment: It Searches in System Tables...Not in User tables.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I had copied and pasted what I was trying out querying the master database but you can replace that database name with the name of the one you are using.

Comment: and to get the table name qualified with schema, join `sys.schemas` as well: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48173311/1026)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
EXECUTE [MyLinkedServer].[MyLinkedDB].dbo.sp_executesql
   N'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ...'
```

And fill in the where clause depending on what you want to search for?

An alternative would be creating a view that selects from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and then you query that instead.

[Reference for `Information_Schema.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

Comment: Linked Server is not configured for RPC Calls.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on which database your linked server is pointing to. For example, if it is Oracle, you would use Oracle syntax, if it is SQL Server, Sql Server Syntax.

The fact that you are querying the schema through a Linked server shouldnt matter.