# How to convert this existing query to retrieve the same information from a table located in a database on a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query which gives me some nice information about any table on the database.

```
USE [MyDatabase]

SELECT COLUMN_NAME,* 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
```

I would like to modifiy this query so that I get the same information from a table residing on a database on a linked server.

Assuming the full schema of the table is [xxx.xx.x.xx].Database2.dbo.[Table1], how do I rewrite my existing query?

I had a look at this `Stackoverflow` question but the answers do not meet my requirements: [How to list all tables & columns names of a linked-server database in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917635/how-to-list-all-tables-columns-names-of-a-linked-server-database-in-sql-server)

Comment: Did you try `[server].[database].[information_Schema].[columns]`?

Comment: No, I didn't but I just gave it a try and it works!! Please post as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 4 parts identifier:

`[server].[database].[information_Schema].[columns]`

`[server]` being the linked server name,
`[database]` being the relevant database in the linked server.